# Check whether an Object is empty or null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and added a column called `SellQty` and a `Checkbox` at index 0. User has to enter `int` value when he selects a `checkbox`. If not I am showing a message to enter the value. Now the problem is I am getting the value from the `SellQty` cell and storing it in an `object` and checking whether it is `null`.

```
object SellQty = gvProductBatch.Rows[i].Cells["txtSellQty"].Value;
if(SellQty!=null)
    // do something

else 
    // ..Show message.
```

This works fine. But the problem is when the user enters a value and deletes it, the value stored in it is `{}` i.e. empty. I would like to know how to check an object is empty. I have googled for the same but didn't find answer to handle empty object. All results were for if object is null.

Comment: TypeCast the object to string, and then check if it is null or empty...

Comment: You mean the value `{}` is a `DBNull`. So you can check e.g. `if (SellQty == DBNull.Value)`

Comment: Why save it as an `object` when it's a `string`?

Comment: maybe assign to a string `gvProductBatch.Rows[i].Cells["txtSellQty"].Value as string` and then check using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method

Comment: @StuartDunkeld, V4Vendetta - What if the user clears the entry by selecting it and hitting space.

Comment: @asawyer dude..that is the exact problem I am trying to explain.

Comment: @Gopesh and Stuart... Isstringnullorempty wont work because the cell value is null.We cannot get SellQty.Tostring().

Comment: @user2002785 The point I was getting at was that `String.IsNullOrEmpty` would return a false positive for non empty whitespace string values. Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: @ybee - as per my knowledge DBNULL is used for database values I guess.

Comment: @asawyer IsNullOrWhiteSpace is only available in framework 4 or later

Comment: It doesn't matter if we are using WhiteSpace or empty. We cannot validate it because this gvProductBatch.Rows[i].Cells["txtSellQty"].Value returns an object.So it is null we cannot use .Tostring.

Comment: @user2002785: `System.DBNull` is a .NET equivalent for SQL `DBNULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the actual edited Value by using the `.EditedFormattedValue`

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gvProductBatch.Rows[i].Cells["txtSellQty"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString())
{
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: I am using 3.5.Anywaz I have used NullorEmpty and it works great.Thanks mate.Can you just explain a bit about this line of code.

Comment: heres the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.editedformattedvalue.aspx) reference will explain to you. welcome `:)`

Comment: Gone through it.Thanks.I have changed the validation and calculations in my entire module.It works great. I didn't handle this exception when user enters a white space in whole module.Now it works great

Comment: you use like this way. `if (gvProductBatch.Rows[i].Cells["txtSellQty"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
{
  //Do something
}`